# Can hardware breakpoints (x86 debug registers) at interrupt handler cause double fault?

Tags: debugging, linux-kernel, x86, interrupt-handling, interrupted-exception

I was wondering if setting an x86 Debug Register (hardware breakpoint) at interrupt context may cause a double/triple fault?